# Nodejs Express Passport - Difference between req.isAuthenticated() and req.user

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

If a user has authenticated, shouldn't the request have a user attached to it, as well as returning `true` for `req.isAuthenticated()`?

So what is the difference between these two then? Shouldn't I be fine just checking if req.user exists, in terms of making sure the user logged in?

Answer (score 0):

I was also wondering about this.  I am not exactly sure what the underlying logic is behind `req.isAuthenticated()` and how it differs to just checking if `req.user` exists.  However as far as I understand, I think yes, you would be fine just checking if `req.user` exists, to determine if someone is logged in or not.  However, using `req.isAuthenticated()` might be a better semantic choice, making the code more readable.